# MongoDB query against geospatial index with maxDistance fails from node.js client

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing, geospatial, mongoskin

I want to query against a geospatial index in mongo-db (designed after this tutorial http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing).

So when I execute this from the shell everything works fine:

```
db.sellingpoints.find(( { location : { $near: [48.190120, 16.270895], $maxDistance: 7 / 111.2 } } );
```

but the same query from my nodejs application (using mongoskin or mongoose), won't return any results until i set the distance-value to a very high number (5690)

```
db.collection('sellingpoints')
 .find({ location: { $near: [lat,lng], $maxDistance: distance / 111.2} })
 .limit(limit)
 .toArray(callback);
```

Has someone any idea how to fix that?

Comment: have you tried the same query but replacing distance/X calculation with a constant (to rule out syntax related problem)?

Comment: when I set $maxDistance to a constant value (e.g.$maxDistance: 0.0629496402877697841726618705036) I get no results

Comment: are you sure your lat, lng are set to correct values in nodejs app?

Comment: yes i log every param and their types before passing them to the query, the configuration is the same when working from the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried a simple node mongoose script against some geo localized data. I'm using the cities geo data from http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite, loading it all into mongodb.
I've wrote a small test code for this (https://github.com/nleite/mongoose_test).

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.createConnection( 'localhost', 'geo');

var schema = mongoose.Schema( { city: 'string', loc: 'array', areaCode: 'string', country:      'string', region: 'string', locId: 'string', metroCode: 'string', postalCode: 'string'} );

var City = db.model( 'City', schema);
var distance = 7 / 111.2;
console.log( 'Distance %s', distance);
var query = City.find( { 'loc':  { $near: [48.190120, 16.270895], $maxDistance: distance      }} ); 
query.exec( function( err, city){
   if (err) return handleError(err);
   console.log( 'Found you %s' , city);
   process.exit(-1);
});
```

It seems to be working pretty well. I've even took your query to check if there could be any problem with it, but seems to be working fine.

Can you please give as more info on the Schema and the Query that is not working as you expected ?

Comment: hi, thanks for your help,
the problem was the index which had no min/max specified (env issues)

Answer (score 2):

All mongo geo query should be in format of (long,lat)  and NOT (lat,long).
Can you try with that format.

PS : you need to ensure data is inserted in (long,lat) format as well as query in also (long,lat) format